# .NET (4.5) ListView - add/remove column bug(?)

Tags: vb.net, listview

I came across an awkward (that is, unexpected for me) behaviour of the .NET Listview. The issue may have been posted before. If so, apologies for the duplication: I didn't find it and would appreciate being pointed to "the" discussion.

Context: I'm using VisualStudio 2013, VB, target framework 4.5

Build a Form with a listview and a few buttons.
The ListView (Details-view) is initially configured with 1 column labeled "1" and 2 rows, each containing a "1".

Then there's a button to Add a column with header "A" (if it's not there yet) and for each listviewItem a subitem "a". Likewise for a column "B" with subitem "b".
Finally there are buttons to remove columns "A" and "B" respectively.

Now, if I do the following:

1. Add "A"
2. Delete "A"
3. Add "B"

I wind up with a column "B" (header) with column contents "a", i.e. those of the "removed" column "A".
Playing around you always find that upon removal of a column (listview.columns.removeBykey('key'), for instance) the subitems seem to persist "invisibly" and come to life if "any" columnHeader is added later on.

I'm not looking for help to solve a programming problem: there's an easy way around (whenever you remove a column, also remove explicitly the corresponding subitems from each listviewItem), but it puzzles me that this clumsy (in my view) approach would be necessary.
Maybe I don't properly use/configure the listview and should have known all this. Any comment is appreciated.

I copy the code below, to make it easier to verify for anyone interested.

(Designer code)

```
    <Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class Form1
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
    'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Me.lvStd = New System.Windows.Forms.ListView()
    Me.btnAdd_A = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.btnDel_A = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.btnAdd_B = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.btnDel_B = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    '
    'lvStd
    '
    Me.lvStd.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Top
    Me.lvStd.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
    Me.lvStd.Name = "lvStd"
    Me.lvStd.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(661, 207)
    Me.lvStd.TabIndex = 0
    Me.lvStd.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = False
    Me.lvStd.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details
    '
    'btnAdd_A
    '
    Me.btnAdd_A.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 235)
    Me.btnAdd_A.Name = "btnAdd_A"
    Me.btnAdd_A.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
    Me.btnAdd_A.TabIndex = 1
    Me.btnAdd_A.Text = "Add A"
    Me.btnAdd_A.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'btnDel_A
    '
    Me.btnDel_A.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 264)
    Me.btnDel_A.Name = "btnDel_A"
    Me.btnDel_A.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
    Me.btnDel_A.TabIndex = 2
    Me.btnDel_A.Text = "Del A"
    Me.btnDel_A.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'btnAdd_B
    '
    Me.btnAdd_B.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(159, 235)
    Me.btnAdd_B.Name = "btnAdd_B"
    Me.btnAdd_B.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
    Me.btnAdd_B.TabIndex = 3
    Me.btnAdd_B.Text = "Add B"
    Me.btnAdd_B.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'btnDel_B
    '
    Me.btnDel_B.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(159, 264)
    Me.btnDel_B.Name = "btnDel_B"
    Me.btnDel_B.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
    Me.btnDel_B.TabIndex = 4
    Me.btnDel_B.Text = "Del B"
    Me.btnDel_B.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'Form1
    '
    Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
    Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
    Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(661, 474)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.btnDel_B)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.btnAdd_B)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.btnDel_A)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.btnAdd_A)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.lvStd)
    Me.Name = "Form1"
    Me.Text = "Form1"
    Me.ResumeLayout(False)

  End Sub
  Friend WithEvents lvStd As System.Windows.Forms.ListView
  Friend WithEvents btnAdd_A As System.Windows.Forms.Button
  Friend WithEvents btnDel_A As System.Windows.Forms.Button
  Friend WithEvents btnAdd_B As System.Windows.Forms.Button
  Friend WithEvents btnDel_B As System.Windows.Forms.Button

End Class
```

and the "Form" code:

```
Public Class Form1

  Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnLoad(e)
    If (Me.DesignMode) Then Return

    Me.Configure()
    Me.FillList()

  End Sub

  Private Sub Configure()
    Me.lvStd.BeginUpdate()
    Me.lvStd.Clear()
    Me.lvStd.Columns.Add("1")
    Me.lvStd.EndUpdate()
  End Sub

  Private Sub FillList()
    Dim LI As ListViewItem
    For k As Integer = 1 To 2
      LI = Me.lvStd.Items.Add("1")
    Next
  End Sub

  Private Sub btnAdd_A_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd_A.Click

    Dim col As ColumnHeader = Me.lvStd.Columns("A")
    If (col IsNot Nothing) Then
      Return
    End If

    Me.lvStd.Columns.Add("A", "A")

    For Each LI As ListViewItem In Me.lvStd.Items
      LI.SubItems.Add("a")
    Next

  End Sub

  Private Sub btnDel_A_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDel_A.Click

    Dim col As ColumnHeader = Me.lvStd.Columns("A")
    If (col IsNot Nothing) Then
      Me.lvStd.Columns.Remove(col)
    End If

  End Sub

  Private Sub btnAdd_B_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd_B.Click

    Dim col As ColumnHeader = Me.lvStd.Columns("B")
    If (col IsNot Nothing) Then
      Return
    End If

    Me.lvStd.Columns.Add("B", "B")

    For Each LI As ListViewItem In Me.lvStd.Items
      LI.SubItems.Add("b")
    Next

  End Sub

  Private Sub btnDel_B_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDel_B.Click

    Dim col As ColumnHeader = Me.lvStd.Columns("B")
    If (col IsNot Nothing) Then
      Me.lvStd.Columns.Remove(col)
    End If

  End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Interesting that if you Add B, Del B and then Add A you get the 'inverse' of the problem you describe. Seems to indicate that you are looking at a 'feature' of the ListView.

Comment: Looks like a simple mistake, you forgot to delete the subitem when you remove the column.  So when you add a column again then they will show up again.  You see the old subitem and can't see the new one.

Comment: @HP: "mistake" and "forgot": see my comment and "work around". My post was about that I had EXPECTED that "column.remove(...)" would not only remove the Header from the headers collection, but also the column(contents). Now that I "know" I won't "forget" anymore, but I find it counter-intuitive.

Comment: Well, you "learned" something "new".  Congratulations.